# Add margin for card boostrap in owl carousel

Tags: css, owl-carousel

i have trouble when tried to give margin on card from bootsrap 4 in owl carousel, it doesn't make any changes i already tried to give margin on .card (css) and on .owl-corausel (java script)

on css

```
.card {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

on js

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
stagePadding: 1,
loop:true,
margin:10,
responsiveClass:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1,
        nav:true
    },
    600:{
        items:3,
        nav:false
    },
    1000:{
        items:5,
        nav:true,
        loop:false
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do:

```
margin-right 10px !important;
```

The problem might be that you are trying to overwrite a default Boostrap style. Adding "!important" will solve that problem.